# Python PyGame image (Donkey Kong) not moving

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have made a simple pygame that should move a donkey image left and right with the arrow keys. The Donkey image is in the folder and already appears, but it does not move left and right. I am on python 3.7 if that helps.

I have look for more then half and hour and I don't understand why it is not working, please help.

This is My Code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
charx = 1
chary = 1
vel = 10
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame")
char = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('donkey.jpg'), (128, 128))

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(10)

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        charx = charx - vel
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        charx = charx + vel
    else:
        run = False
    run = True

    win.blit(char,(charx, chary))
    pygame.display.update()
```

When I run the program the window shows up and there is Donkey Kong in the top left corner. But he does not move with the arrow keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why, but if you add the event loop it works.
You also need to move the `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` line inside the `while` loop.

```
while run:
    #add the following 3 lines, to check over events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        charx = charx - vel
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        charx = charx + vel
    else:
        run = False
    run = True

    win.blit(char,(charx, chary))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(10)
```

I can only guess that `pygame.key.get_pressed()` doesn't work properly if `pygame.event.get()` is not consumed in the main loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked except for sys.exit() part. I think I need to import sys or something. Idk

Comment: Yes. `import sys`. This will allow program termination when you click on the x to close the window.